# Tkinter: How to get the button which is inside a canvas.window()

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I would like to understand how I could get hold of a `button` widget which is part of a `canvas.window()` item, to change its properties.

```
button1 = Button(self, text = "Quit", command = self.quit, anchor = W)
button1.configure(width = 10, activebackground = "#33B5E5", relief = FLAT)
button1_window = canvas1.create_window(10, 10, anchor=NW, window=button1)
```

In the above code snippet you can see that I'm embedding a button inside a window. Then, I'm embedding this window on a `canvas`.

Now, when a user clicks on the `button1_window` item, I would like to take control of the button inside that window and then change its properties for e.g. the border size/color.

Comment: I see you have `self` there, implying a standard OO Tkinter app. You should be able to make `button1` an instance attribute with `self.button1 = ...` and then refer to it easily from anywhere in the class.

Comment: The snippet is not part of my actual program. In my program, the user has an option of creating many windows (basically icons) on the canvas and also delete them when he likes to. I don't want to keep track of the creation/deletion of windows/buttons. Whenever the user clicks on a window (an icon) I would like to then take control of the button inside it and change its properties.

Comment: In that case, can you edit your question to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can work with?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to take control of the button inside that window and then
>   change its properties for e.g. the border size/color.

If you `bind()` a function to a button, then when the button is clicked tkinter will pass an `event object` as an argument to the function.  The `event object` has a `widget` property, which will be the button that was clicked.  Here is an example of what you can do:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 

        canvas = tk.Canvas(
                    self, 
                    width = 300, 
                    height = 200)
        canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,300,200, fill="red")
        canvas.pack()

        button_texts = ['hello', 'world', 'goodbye', 'mars']

        for i, button_text in enumerate(button_texts):
            button = tk.Button(text=button_text)
            button.bind("<Button-1>", self.onclickButton)

            canvas.create_window(
                   100, 50 + 30*i,
                   window=button,
            )


    def onclickButton(self, evt):
        evt.widget.config(padx=100)
        print(evt.widget.cget('text'))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300+10+0")
MyFrame(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I understand this. But now imagine a case when, lets say I click the 'world' button (or any other) then that button gets highlighted. And I want to remove the highlight from 'goodbye' button. How can I do that? How can I take control of the 'goodbye' button? Or if I click the rectangle area, how can I remove any highlights on the buttons? Revert them back to original looks.